# finding the sum in matrix element neighbour

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

=== solved ===

I need to find for each element of matrix sum of his neighbour and write it to another matrix.
For example: 
`matrix[0][0]`

```
matrix2[0][0] = matrix[-1][0] + matrix[0][-1] + matrix[1][0] + matrix[0][1]

1 2 3
3 4 5
5 6 7
```

for [0][0] - 2 + 3 + 3 + 5

**Input Matrix:**

```
matrix = []
tmp = []
answer = []
inp = ''
while inp != 'end':
  tmp = [int(i) for i in input().split() if i != 'end']
  if len(tmp) == 0: inp = 'end'
  else: matrix.append(tmp)
  tmp = []
```

Now I don't know which "if...else" condition is needed to complete this task.

**Current Code:**

```
for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
  for j in range(0, len(matrix[i])):
    summ = 0
    if i-1 >= 0:
      summ += matrix[i-1][j]
    elif i-1 < 0:
      summ += matrix[-1][j]

    if i+1 > len(matrix)-1:
      summ += matrix[0][j]
    elif i+1 <= len(matrix)-1:
      summ += matrix[i+1][j]

    if j-1 >= 0:
      summ += matrix[i][j-1]  
    elif j-1 < 0:
      summ += matrix[i][-1]

    if j+1 > len(matrix[i])-1:
      summ += matrix[i][0]
    elif j+1 <= len(matrix[i])-1:
      summ += matrix[i][j+1]
    answer[i][j] = summ
    continue
```

Can someone point out what's wrong with my code?

**Solved:**

```
   matrix = []
    tmp = []
    answer = []
    inp = ''
    flg = 1
    while inp != 'end':
      tmp = [int(i) for i in input().split() if i != 'end']
      if len(tmp) == 0: inp = 'end'
      else: matrix.append(tmp)
      tmp = []
    tmp = []
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
      if len(matrix)==1 and len(matrix[i])==1:
        summ = matrix[0][0] *4
        flg = 0
        answer.append(summ)
        break
      for j in range(0, len(matrix[i])):
        summ = 0

        if i-1 >= 0:
          summ += matrix[i-1][j]
        elif i-1 < 0:
          summ += matrix[-1][j]

        if i+1 > len(matrix)-1:
          summ += matrix[0][j]
        elif i+1 <= len(matrix)-1:
          summ += matrix[i+1][j]

        if j-1 >= 0:
          summ += matrix[i][j-1]
        elif j-1 < 0:
          summ += matrix[i][-1]

        if j+1 > len(matrix[i])-1:
          summ += matrix[i][0]
        elif j+1 <= len(matrix[i])-1:
          summ += matrix[i][j+1]

        tmp.append(summ)
        continue
      answer.append(tmp)
      tmp = []

    i=j=0
    if flg:
      for i in range(0, len(answer)):
        for j in range(0, len(answer[i])):
          print(answer[i][j], ' ', end='')
        print('')
    if not flg:
      print(summ)
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly, as indentation matters.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [5, 6, 7]]
>>> def neighbors(i,j,a):
...     return [a[i][j-1], a[i][(j+1)%len(a[0])], a[i-1][j], a[(i+1)%len(a)][j]]
...
>>> [[sum(neighbors(i,j,a)) for j in range(len(a[0]))] for i in range(len(a))]
[[13, 14, 15],
 [15, 16, 17],
 [17, 18, 19]]
>>> a.append([100, 200, 300])
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [5, 6, 7],
 [100, 200, 300]]
>>> [[sum(neighbors(i,j,a)) for j in range(len(a[0]))] for i in range(len(a))]
[[108, 208, 308],
 [15, 16, 17],
 [116, 216, 316],
 [506, 408, 310]]
```

Comment: 1. Is there a particular reason for returning a list of the neighboring values rather than their sum? My guess is "it's more generic hence reusable" --- 2. In the OP we  have an example revolving around a square matrix, but  the code is completely generic and, imho, even suggests the need to consider a non-square matrix.

Comment: 1. yep, it's a bit more generic (although I probably should use better function name). 2. also true, then it's better to change a -> a[0] for j. Updated.

Comment: Can you explain this: a[i][(j+1)%len(a[0])] and a[(i+1)%len(a)][j]?

Comment: I preferred the version with the `a if .. else b` constructs, the intent of the operation was immediate while one has to think a bit with your current solution... another small issue,  if you go back to the `a if ... else b` solutionyou should split the returned list on four rows, as it would be a little longish otherwise

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]
>>> b=[]
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
...    tmp=[]
...    for j in range(len(a[0])):
...       tmp.append(a[(i+1)%len(a)][j]+a[(i-1)%len(a)][j]+a[i][(j+1)%len(a[0])]+a[i][(j-1)%len(a[0])])
...    b.append(tmp)
... 
>>> b
[[13, 14, 15], [15, 16, 17], [17, 18, 19]]
```